# Problemas com uma consulta MYSQL - Categorias e Itens

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou a fazer um projeto, que basicamente se consiste em item e categoria... ou melhor "animes" e "episodios"...

Eis o problema, eu quero listar todos os animes cadastrados e uma contagem dos episódios relacionados a eles, por exemplo. "Katekyo - 24 episodios"... isso eu consegui, porem na lista só vem os animes que estão com episódios relacionados a eles, os animes que não estão com episódios não aparecem na consulta!

Atualmente

Tabela Animes

```
id_anime   nome_anime   capa_anime   visualizacoes_anime
1          Anime1       capa.png     250
2          Anime2       capa.png     250
3          Anime2       capa.png     250
```

Tabela Episódios

```
id_episodio   numero_episodio   capa_episodio   visualizacoes_episodio   id_anime
1             Episodio1         capa.png        250                      1
2             Episodio2         capa.png        250                      1
3             Episodio2         capa.png        250                      2
```

Consulta

```
SELECT nome_anime, animes.id_anime as id_do_anime, COUNT(id_episodio) as quantidade_epis 
FROM animes INNER JOIN episodios_animes ON animes.id_anime = episodios_animes.id_anime 
GROUP BY episodios_animes.id_anime
```

Como resultado vem

```
nome_anime   id_do_anime   quantidade_epis
Anime1       1             2
Anime2       2             1
```

Problema é que só vem os que estão com episódios contando, o anime 3 que não tem episódio não veio na lista, e eu queria que viesse todos, e se não tiver episódio nele, venha um zero no caso!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitua o `INNER JOIN` de sua query por um `LEFT JOIN`.

Ao não existir valor na tabela a direita, ele ainda trará o resultado da tabela a esquerda com os valores da direita nulos.

Para trazer ordenado conforme últimos episódios inseridos, basta fazer um `ORDER BY episodios_animes.id_episodio DESC`, uma vez que os últimos inseridos teram os maiores id's.

```
SELECT
  nome_anime,
  animes.id_anime as id_do_anime,
  COUNT(id_episodio) as quantidade_epis 
FROM animes
LEFT JOIN episodios_animes ON animes.id_anime = episodios_animes.id_anime 
GROUP BY animes.id_anime
ORDER BY episodios_animes.id_episodio DESC
```

[Veja funcionando no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de4f8a/7)

Comment: Obrigado por responder... seguinte, mudei para LEFT, mas em vez de vim todos os animes, veio os animes que estao com os episodios e apenas veio 1 com o o valor 0... no total tem 23 animes.

Comment: @ViniciusVieira tente mudar seu `GROUP BY` para `animes.id`. Consegue disponibilidar um http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Funcionou meu querido, obrigado... ai vai o fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de4f8a/1

tenho so mais uma duvida, como listar animes em mostrando em cima os ultimos que foram adicionado episodios neles... tipo

anime5 25 episodios
anime2 29 episodios
anime1 0  episodios
anime4 0  episodios

Obrigado

Comment: Aqui está funcionando como disse o Vinicius: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d01/2

Comment: @LuisHenrique adicioneio o sqlfiddle na sua resposta. Se não gostar reverta a edição.

Comment: Obrigado tambem Jorge pela ajuda, graças esta funcionando tudo beleza!

Comment: Sem problemas @JorgeB. +1 pela colaboração.

Comment: @ViniciusVieira editei a query na minha resposta com o seu pedido de ordenação, f5 ae.

Comment: Olha que beleza, ficou top! muito obrigado mesmo a vcs! salvaram minha vida cambada! ^^

Comment: ai funcionou massa...
http://i.imgur.com/juKEast.png